# Where can I find documentation on "python imbricated functions"

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have seen python functions defined within other function like this:

```py
def une_fonction(fonction):

    def autre_fonction(*param, **param2):
        print "Action avant .............. "
        fonction(*param, **param2)
        print "Action après .............."

    return autre_fonction
```

- Anyone can tell me where I can find official documentation or tutorials on this?
- Why and how are they used?

Comment: The official documentation is here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions

Comment: This has less to do with functions in particular, but more with scope in general. This might help: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example